# Owin Self host httpconfiguration cannot be resolved

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, oauth, console-application, owin

The problem is when I create the Startup class in my Console Project, after getting the newest Owin Self Host from NuGet (and changed my target platform to net45), it cannot resolve the HttpConfiguration class?

```
public class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        var config = new HttpConfiguration();
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute("default", "{controller}");
        app.UseWebApi(config);
    }
}
```

What did I miss? It's the first time I try to play around with this Web API thing for my backend service, and without the configuration it's hard to get started with the WebAPI and OWIN. It's probably something simple that I missed?

Comment: exposed code is not enough. What r u trying to do

Comment: It's quiet simple, I just try to enable web api to a console project, but I Cannon proceed with it due to the fact that I Cannon setup the Startup Class's ctor

Answer (score 0):

Basic things to check is that you have reference to `System.Web.Http` assembly in your project and added `using System.Web.Http;` statement.

Comment: I'm not that new to c# :-D The reference is there, and they are btw auto added when Owin self host is being installed from the nuget manager.